# LittleFS File system - stm32H753BI Cache Issue

Tags: memory, embedded, stm32

When I enable Instruction Cache my LFS filesystem gets corrupts.  File cannot open.
If I disable the Instruction cache, then file Operations takes places successfully.

SCB_EnableICache();

Note: LFS does not use Dynamic memory and DMA access.

Comment: Did you call `SCB_InvalidateICache` before? If not then do that. If it works then I'll explain further

Comment: This FS is far from being even OK. For example how to recover form error (from the github issues authors advice): delete all files in the directory, then delete the directory. A bit weird as for the FAIL SAFE file system

Answer (score 0):

If your code doesn't use dynamic code in ram (like thunks) and you don't manipulate the PC in any ways the Instruction cache is perfectly transparent afaik. Probably the performance boost make some race conditions to come out.